# Ruby display address with commas

Tags: ruby

Hi I have an organisation model that accepts nested attributes for an address model. Everything is working fine but when I try and display the address, the best I've come up with so far is:-

```
<%= "#{@organisation.address.line1} #{@organisation.address.line2} #{@organisation.address.line3} #{@organisation.address.line4} #{@organisation.address.postcode} #{@organisation.address.country}" %>
```

This works, but it doesn't add a comma between the fields. I can manually add a comma, but that looks silly if the address doesn't have a line4 etc.

Is there an easier way to do this so that the address displays like below and doesn't add a comma after a field if it's blank (and also adds a full stop after the last field)?

```
The address, the road, the postcode, the country.
```

Thanks for looking

**Edit**

Thanks for all the suggestions. I'm going to try create a helper method on the application controller that can be called from any view because the address model is used by multiple other models.

Comment: Use .join on an array of those games with blank items removed?

Comment: Unrelated, but code like this belongs in a presenter somewhere, or at the very least in a helper that takes an address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= [@organisation.address.line1, @organisation.address.line2, @organisation.address.line3, @organisation.address.line4, @organisation.address.postcode, @organisation.address.country].reject(&:blank?).join(", ") %>
```

It would be better to move it to a helper though

Comment: I've created a helper method on my application controller using .reject(&:blank?).join(", ") but can't figure out how to add a full stop to the end. Any ideas?

Comment: `[].reject(&:blank?).join(', ') + "."`

Answer (score 1):

You can go like this:

```
<%= "#{@organisation.address.line1},#{@organisation.address.line2},\
     #{@organisation.address.line3},#{@organisation.address.line4},\
     #{@organisation.address.postcode},#{@organisation.address.country}".
     gsub(/,+/,",").gsub(/(\A,)|(,\Z)/,'')%>
```

This way you kill double commas and also any commas appearing at start or end of the string

Comment: This will work, but IMO it's a sub-optimal solution for readability and maintenance.

Comment: I agree. I didn't post an array answer because you'd already left the comment. However, this is an approach with `gsub` which IMHO should not be selected but be there for people to see in any future reference.

Answer (score 1):

@Vimsha answer is correct, however, I would go a step further and override the `to_string` method on the Address model:

```
def self.to_s
    [line1, line2, line3, line4, postcode, country].reject(&:blank?).join(", ")
end
```

Then you can easily call it on the view:

```
<%= @organization.address.to_s %>
```

EDIT:  You want to override `to_s`, not `to_string`

Comment: I'd hesitate to clutter the model with view-specific logic.

Comment: Not view specific.  `to_s` is a Method on the Ruby Object class to present a string representation of the object.  This way, you can reuse this string representation throughout the application.

Comment: ... I'm skeptical this is used throughout the application in a non-view later. Either way, I don't think this belongs in the model proper.

Comment: @DaveNewton where would it belong? in a helper?

Comment: i'd put it in a helper, yeah.

Comment: @DaveNewton If you isolate the method to a helper, then you would have to replicate the function in all other helpers for views, in this case, that are not served by the OrganizationsController.  Since Address is its own model, I am assuming that the OP intends on associating address with other models.

Answer (score 1):

For view-specific methods, consider using decorators. You add a layer of decorators and put view-specific methods there. Google "rails and decorators"

Moving on to how it should be done:

```
address = @organization.address
array = [address.line1, address.line2, address.city]
"#{array.join(', ')}." # also look into the "to_sentence" method
```

If you want to exclude nil entries, use compact before the join.

If you want to exclude blank entries, use

```
array.reject(&:blank?)
```

If you're looking to add entries in the array based on their presence, then the following would be suitable.

```
array = [].tap do |arr|
  arr << address.line1 if address.line1.present?
  # and so on
end
```

Comment: This would include blank/nil entries.

Comment: Thanks @DaveNewton for pointing it out. I've now edited the response to make it more comprehensive.

Answer (score 1):

```
[line_1, line_2, city, "#{state} #{zip}".strip].compact.join(', ')
```